# How to get W2 answer from unresponsive institution?

Tags: w2

I work for the City of New York (CUNY), and I've held the same position for about 15 years. This year for the first time, a standard line on my W2 was missing. I inquired to my college HR about why that was. I got several weeks of runaround, no answer to my question, but then received a corrected W2.

Now the corrected W2 includes the expected line -- notably increasing my taxable income to a higher-than-expected amount. Unlike prior years, the overall numbers don't add up properly when I double-check them. I asked HR about this and was told there was a deduction to the line in question which is not reflected in the total compensation (hence the higher total) and not visible on my W2. I inquired how I could verify or find out about this new hidden difference in the future, and was referred to an outside city agency.

Now for the last 3 weeks (up to the tax filing deadline yesterday), I've been calling and emailing this city office on a daily basis and they seem unable to respond to my question. Every day I'm told that they'll get back in another day, or they apologize and promise to call back in 15 minutes, but they never do. They've asked for multiple pieces of supporting documentation which I've sent but to which they never respond or confirm receipt, until I call again. They receive but never reply to emails.

What's the best way to approach an apparently stone-walling institution regarding a W2 question like that? It's frustrating to spend time and mental energy every day making that same phone call.

Comment: which line is the one you were missing?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: I'd prefer not to say. The thrust of this question is how to best interface with the unresponsive institution.

Comment: I like Mister Positive's answer because it does apply directly to the question, but I did want to ask.. Did you file something (an extension or a rough information return) with the IRS by last night despite not having all of the correct information? I'm by no means a tax expert but it is my understanding that even if you aren't ready to file or pay by the deadline, if they hear about your status from you by then, you wont be assessed a late penalty.. I don't think It is that big of a deal to correct a previous year's filing if some of the data changes after the initial filing.

Comment: @Smitty: I filed and paid my taxes using the existing information.

Comment: OK good..  Ive always found the IRS pretty easy to work with and non-punitive as long as you mind the lines of communication and deadlines... I didnt make this an answer because I run 1099 and Im not on solid advice ground in context with your situation.. just wanted to make sure you werent waiting on a w2 to file...  In my case, I would have done the same as you and filed to the best of my ability and ignored this other party dragging their feet.. Grain of salt though... I dont really know if I am just an audit away from this being terrible advice.. good luck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they haven't sent you an accurate W2 by Feb 12, you can call the IRS at (800)829-1040 and file a complaint with them, and then the IRS will contact your employer. Most people tend to not like getting called by the IRS.

If you want to know ahead of time whether you're going have this on your W2, and you're getting the run-around, then the response is to escalate it. Inform your boss of what's going on, and find out who the boss is of the people who are giving you the run-around, and complain to them. If nothing else works, consider emailing the regents, mayor, city council, etc. and complaining to them. This isn't guaranteed to get what you want, but at the very least it makes not giving you what you want inconvenient for other people.

Comment: +1 because sometimes  "*it makes not giving you what you want inconvenient for other people*" is all you have to work with.

Comment: In the interest of having a selected answer (much later), I'm picking this one. With the following caveats: (a) only follow-up if the correction is to my benefit, and (b) first try to pursue a correction in-house. Once I got shuffled off to an outside agency, then complaining to the IRS would be a strong option. (I've also added a reflective answer of my own currently below.)

Answer (score 4):

> What's the best way to approach an apparently stone-walling
>   institution regarding a W2 question like that?

I think at this point your best bet it to pay them a **visit in person**.  Bring all your supporting documentation, and have someone address your concerns face to face.

It is *much harder to ignore* you when your standing in front of the individual who should be helping you.  Of course this answer makes the assumption that paying a visit is **realistic**.

This approach has worked for me in similar cases, YMMV.

Comment: I don't think this would work. Just showing up at the front desk of a large bureaucratic organization without an appointment with a specific person will get you nowhere. You could try to make an appointment but this will likely result in the same run around: there is just no one in charge for dealing with it.

Comment: Interestingly, this is also the advice I just got from my college HR today.

Answer (score 1):

> Now for the last 3 weeks (up to the tax filing deadline yesterday)

So, you *did* file your fed and state taxes... right?
(If you filed the IRS extension request this is the same thing **if** you are owed a refund)

**If not**, file them **now** *with your current W-2 information* **and pay what you owe**.
If it turns out your taxes are lower, you can file an amended return once you have proof of that.

AND call the IRS like Acccumulation said.
AND if you can figure out how to implement Mister Positive's answer, do that also.

Answer (score -3):

Returning to this question a few years later to add (as OP) how I'd actually handle this if it happened again today, as an option to others if they read this. And that would be:

**Do literally nothing at all.**

In this particular case, correcting the missing line on my W2 was only going to add to my income and hence my tax burden, and I would have been better off simply remaining silent on the issue. If the W2 gets revised at a later date, of course, I'd be prepared to submit a revised filing and correct the tax payment as needed. But driving myself nuts chasing after unresponsive bureaucracy to my own detriment was not a good strategy (although for some of us bordering on OCD, hard to avoid).

On the other hand, if there was a mistake that was clearly in my disfavor, and would help me if corrected, then I'd probably pursue that again in the future. If that happened, then I'd try really hard to keep the communication within my own institution (where it's easier to get a name, and, if needed, show up in person), and likely punt once it got shuffled off to an outside bureaucracy. Even there I'd want to do a risk-analysis of what the likely time-expense was on my end, versus the increased tax payment, before spending that time.

(As a follow-up, the error in question has not re-appeared in the 2 years since.)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: No. I consider the suggestion here to be a "good-faith effort at using the information as provided by my employer" (e.g., language on 1040 signing statement, "to the best of my knowledge"). The time I spent on this case didn't fully resolve it, and I see no path forward at my organization where it ever could have been resolved. If you have a citation/case that a good-faith use of employer's documentation was counted as "cheating" and penalties assigned as such, then of course I'd be very interested in seeing that.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: So, as expected, no actual citation of a specific case. Not very interested in internet-argument to no end.